# How to deal with the CMake Error: Target DependInfo.cmake file not found

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I used CLion to write some c++ source files(The specific code are not important as far as this question is concerned). However, one project can only have one main() function although these main() functions are in different source files. So in the CMakeLists.txt:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.20)
project(_CODE__20220116_CppTyro)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 17)

add_executable(_CODE__20220116_CppTyro main.cpp 0001HelloWorld.cpp 0002Square.cpp)

add_executable(0001HelloWorld 0001HelloWorld.cpp)
add_executable(0002Square 0002Square.cpp)
```

I wrote these in order to run two or more main() functions in one C++ project.
But an error occurred:

```
====================[ Build | 0001HelloWorld | Debug ]==========================
"D:\CLion 2021.2\bin\cmake\win\bin\cmake.exe" --build (Here is the path of source file)
CMake Error: Target DependInfo.cmake file not found
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/0001HelloWorld.dir/0001HelloWorld.cpp.obj
G__~1.EXE: error: (Here is the path of source file): No such file or directory
G__~1.EXE: fatal error: no input files
compilation terminated.
mingw32-make.exe[3]: *** [CMakeFiles\0001HelloWorld.dir\build.make:71: 
CMakeFiles/0001HelloWorld.dir/0001HelloWorld.cpp.obj] Error 1
mingw32-make.exe[2]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:112: CMakeFiles/0001HelloWorld.dir/all] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe[1]: *** [CMakeFiles\Makefile2:119: CMakeFiles/0001HelloWorld.dir/rule] Error 2
mingw32-make.exe: *** [Makefile:136: 0001HelloWorld] Error 2
```

I don't know why this error occurred and how to deal with it.

Comment: ***wrote these in order to run two or more main() functions in one C++ project.*** You should not do this. add_executable creates only one executable file and that will expect only one entry point i.e. main. Giving multiple source files as input to it each having their own main won't work.

Comment: Is there a source file named `0001HelloWorld.cpp` in the same directory as the `CMakeLists.txt` file? Why are you using these numbers as prefix?

Comment: @fabian That's not a variable or a class and CLion support that the number is the prefix in the name of a file so I think it's feasible.

Comment: @kiner_shah But when I just keep one c++ source file in this project this error still occurred and the info is the same.

Comment: @Mizuyu, try deleting the build folder and create it again and run CMake.

Comment: @kiner_shah I assume "project" refers to `project(_CODE__20220116_CppTyro)` here, not to individual targets and is actually irrelevant for now: The build process does not reach the linking stage, but that's the stage where you'd get into trouble defining the same symbol in multiple translation units.

Comment: @fabian, Yeah I get it, as mentioned in my first comment, multiple source files each having their own main, cannot be added to the same exectuable - reason is as you say, it will fail during linking because of repeated symbols.

Comment: @Mizuyu, how did you solve this issue? Can you post an answer mentioning your solution?

Comment: @kiner_shah I have post the answer.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of kiner_shah, I found the solution.

**That is, never let your name of project and path include '[' or ']', especially in the first letter.**

In my question, I didn't give the specific path of the source file because I thought it was not important. However, I found every time I built this project a new folder would be generated whose name was similar to the path of project. For example:

The project path is

```
D:\[CODE]Language_Learning\[CODE]Cpp_Learning
```

And it will generate a folder named(pay attention to that there is no backword slash)

```
[CODE]Language_Learning[CODE]Cpp_Learning
```

in the disk D, and CLion will find related file in this folder!
Because this was a new folder, there was no file related to this project and an error occurred.
But if the project path is

```
D:\Language_Learning\Cpp_Learning
```

no error occurred.
The reason why it happened is not clear(maybe just a bug), but this question is solved.